# Is fronting Tomcat by Apache http server meaningful when we are using aws application load balancer

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I know fronting Tomcat by Apache has some security benefits when we are using aws classic load balancer. However, I was wondering if it is meaningful to front Tomcat by Apache http server, when we are using aws application load balancer? Because an application load balancer operates at Layer 7 of the OSI model, and deals with application-level content.

Comment: Are you using CloudFront to deliver static assets?

Comment: No, I am not using CloudFront to deliver static assets. The application is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your intention. Fronting tomcat is not an issue when you go with AWS and ALBs are good way to handle and route your traffic. Therefore, stick to ALB rather than ELB and maintaining an Apache layer.